# Change Background Tkinter in Classes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm relatively new to Tkinter and Python and just started with Tkinter in object oriented way.
Im trying to change the background colour of all the different pages I have so i have the following code

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import *

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800

class programStart(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self) 
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=WIDTH)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=HEIGHT)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, Register, LoginPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise() #Raises to front

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
```

I have tried container.configure(bg='red') and so on, to no success

How can I go about this issue?

Comment: Change `frame = F(container, self)` to `frame = F(container, self, bg="red")` and make sure that the `StartPage`, `Register` and `LoginPage` classes accept key word arguments. Can you please post the code of the `__init__` method in the `StartPage`, `Register` and `LoginPage` classes

Comment: Included '__init__' now @TheLizzard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import *

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800

class programStart(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self) 
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=WIDTH)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=HEIGHT) #0 minimum, weight is priority

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, Register, LoginPage):
            frame = F(container, self, bg="red")
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise() #Raises to front

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, bg=None, fg=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg=bg=, fg=fg)
        # Make sure that all of the tkinter widgets have `bg=bg=, fg=fg`
```

Basically you need to tell all of the widgets that you are creating that the background should be red. When creating your widgets you can pass in the `bg` parameter (background).

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimal version of the system I use to give the user of the GUI the ability to change the colors and fonts of all the widgets in the app according to color schemes he can choose himself.

```
import tkinter as tk

formats = {
    'bg' : 'black',
    'fg' : 'white'    
}

class Labelx(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Label.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

    def winfo_subclass(self):
        ''' a method that works like built-in tkinter method
            w.winfo_class() except it gets subclass names
            of widget classes custom-made by inheritance '''
        subclass = type(self).__name__
        return subclass

class Label(Labelx):
    ''' 
        If this subclass is detected it will be reconfigured
        according to user preferences. 
    '''
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Labelx.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.config(
            bg=formats['bg'], 
            fg=formats['fg'])

class LabelNegative(Labelx):
    ''' 
        If this subclass is detected it will be reconfigured
        according to user preferences. 
    '''
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Labelx.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.config(
            bg=formats['fg'], 
            fg=formats['bg'])    

def change_colors():
    for widg in (lab1, lab2):
        if widg.winfo_class() == 'Label':
            if widg.winfo_subclass() == 'Label':
                widg.config(bg=formats['fg'], fg=formats['bg'])
            elif widg.winfo_subclass() == 'LabelNegative':
                widg.config(bg=formats['bg'], fg=formats['fg']) 

root = tk.Tk()

f1 = tk.Frame(root)
f1.grid(column=0, row=0)

lab1 = Label(f1, text='Label')
lab1.grid()

lab2 = LabelNegative(f1, text='LabelNegative')
lab2.grid()

button = tk.Button(root, text='colorize', command=change_colors)
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```